# Is there a way to unlink an specific part of of a <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an card component which I wrapped with  tag. In the  tag, I have added some button. Now the problem is when I click on the button then the  tag sends me to the URL but I don't want to go to a page when I click on a button.

I have tried event.stopPropagation() but It didn't work with  tag. So, if there is any way to solve it please let me know.

Thank you

```html
<a href="/somewhere1">
    <button>Hide</button>

    <div>
        <div>
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000000/fff" alt="" />
            <span>name</span>
        </div>

        <a href="/somewhere2">Title</a>
    </div>
</a>
```

Here I want that the `<button></button>` tag will be unlinkable.

Comment: please post you HTML code

Comment: I have added, it's not full code but it explains the situation.

Comment: You have a link inside a link. Is that intentional?

Comment: Just get rid of the parent link.  Use a span or a div instead.

Comment: button inside link is invalid, link inside link is also invalid. You have to fix this first

Comment: @MuhammadZahidHasan How does this question relate to React.js/Next.js?

Answer (score 0):

heres a little example how you could manage to do it.

```js
const wrapperRef = document.querySelector('#wrapperRef');
wrapperRef.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
if(event.target === wrapperRef.querySelector('button')){
  event.preventDefault();
  //what should happen if you click on button
}
})
```

```html
<a id="wrapperRef" href="/somewhere">
    <button>Hide</button>

    <div>
        <div>
            <img src="" alt="" />
            <span>name</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

You catch the click inside the wrapping a tag, then check if the target that has been clicked on is equal to the inside button. If so you stop redirecting and can add code (I think hiding the href) in the function.

Would be an addition of:

```
wrapperRef.style.display = 'none'
```

or delete it out of the dom:

```
wrapperRef.parentNode.removeChild(wrapperRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an good idea to have nested links inside link. Instead you can wrap your card items in `div` wrapper and locate this whole-card-size link inside it and style it. In Code Snippet below it's called
`.outer-link`. We can stretch it to card size, so whole card will be clickable; Items, that also should be clickable inside this card could be moved in front of stretched links:

```css
.inner-link,
.toggle-button {
  ...
}
```

In this case you don't have to create any JS code to override links behaviour, check Code Snippet:

```js
const btnTrigger = () => {
  console.log('click');
}
```

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
}

/* make link card-size */
.outer-link:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ff634721;
}

/* make inner link and button be in front of full-size link */
.inner-link,
.toggle-button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <button class="toggle-button" onclick="btnTrigger()">Hide</button>

  <div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000000/fff" alt="" />
      <span>name</span>
    </div>

    <a class="inner-link" href="/somewhere2">Title</a>
  </div>
  
  <a class="outer-link" href="/somewhere1"></a>
</div>
```